# ASP NET MVC5 - Forma de habilitar e desabilitar elementos HTML

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

O programa possui na sessão alguns dados do cliente, como CPF e Endereço completo (incluindo estado onde mora).
Se o cliente for de São Paulo, habilita um combo específico, se for de outro estado, nao habilita. Nesse caso, então, eu tenho que verificar a sessão se o estado é São Paulo. A pergunta é: A unica forma de fazer isso é, verificar pelo código e retornar um ajax pro javascript pra desabilitar lá ou tem como eu fazer tudo no C#?

Em webforms eu tinha os controles que me permitiam fazer isso no C#, mas não sei como eu faço isso no MVC já que o unico que tem acesso aos elementos HTML é o javascript.

Forma que eu to fazendo agora:

```
public JsonResult HabilitaCombo()
{
    if (Session["_CliEstado"].ToString() == "São Paulo") {
        return Json(new {habilita = true });
    }
    else
    {
        return Json(new { habilita = false});
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Utilize [`ViewBag`](http://www.devcurry.com/2011/11/viewbag-property-aspnet-mvc-3-is.html), para passar valores do seus métodos para as suas views. Também pode ser [`ViewData`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.viewpage.viewdata%28v=vs.118%29.aspx).

No método:

```
public ActionResult Grafico()
{
    ViewBag._CliEstado = "São Paulo";
}
```

Na View:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Grafico</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>             
        @if (ViewBag._CliEstado != null && ViewBag._CliEstado == "São Paulo")
        {
            <input type="text" id="txtAparecer" name="txtAparecer" />
        }
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Aaah agora está claro! Obrigado!

Answer (score 3):

E se voce usasse o ViewBag?

Usa isso na controller:

```
ViewBag.ClienteSP = VerificaClienteSP();
```

No cshtml:

```
if(@ViewBag.ClienteSP)
{
//habilita ou desabilita os componentes
}
```

Comment: Puxa vou tentar, obrigado!